# How do I view all my kittens?

Tags: kittens-game

When I click on the village/settlement/city tab, I can view my kittens, and see which jobs they are assigned to. However, I can only view at most 10 kittens in each job, even when I have more than 10 assigned to that job. I don't see any "Next Page" button either.

This is an issue when I temporarily move some kittens from one job to another, as they "get lost" in the temporary job if it has more than 10 kittens in it. I do this fairly often with my Scholar kittens, since I have long spans of time when I don't need science.

Is there a way to view all the kittens assigned to a job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently hardcoded to only show 10 kittens in each job, so you cannot view all kittens if you have more then 10 in a job.

Inside the [source](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/village.js?v=1.0.5.8) you can view the following for-loop:

```
for (var i = sim.kittens.length - 1; i >= 0 && kittensLimit < 10; i--)
```

This loop populates (via `this.records.push`) the visible kittens, and the `kittensLimit` max sure there is a maximum of 10 kittens shown. In the update-function (same source) the following for-loop can be found:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.records.length; i++)
```

and the pushed kittens are shown on your screen, with all the council links et cetera.

Comment: So... the answer is no ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot view all kittens assigned to a job